# Design a restful idempotent update of a huge subset of a resource collection

Tags: rest, http, put, hateoas

### Introduction

This is a follow up to [How to design a RESTful collection resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810652/how-to-design-a-restful-collection-resource) . I think the main problem of bulk updates of resources (and bulk deletion) is still unsolved in the provided answers. Hence this new question.

Let's suppose I have a collection resource of `items`

```
http://example.com/items
```

I can retrieve a single `item` via its `item_id` with

```
GET http://example.com/items/{item_id}
```

and request an update of a single item with

```
PUT http://example.com/items/{item_id}
```

Particularly nice about `PUT` is: it is idempotent:

> [**4.2.2 Idempotent methods**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)
>
> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request. Of the request methods defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe request methods are idempotent.

### Problem

**I want to update multiple items in one request.**

I have several options that appear to be undoubtedly "RESTful" but have their drawbacks.

1. request a `PUT` on the collection and send ALL items in the request. (too much overhead if only a small subset of the collection is actually being changed).
2. request a `PATCH` or `POST` on the collection (not idempotent).

As `PUT` and `DELETE` are the only idempotent methods and `DELETE` is clearly not meant for this (cf. [rfc7231 section 4.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)) I need to stick to `PUT`.

### Questions

- How can I achieve this with a "RESTful" API avoiding the aforementioned drawbacks?
- Does the following proposed API comply with REST? If not, why? And which changes could make it work?
- Is this a case where I indeed can not or should not comply with REST?

### Proposal

As a possible solution I came up with the following.

I add a resource for update requests which changes the `items` collection.

```
http://example.com/updateitems
```

- It only permits/accepts `PUT` requests (is that RESTful?) with `multipart/mixed`.
- The requests send a list of full representations of the items which are to be updated.
- The server then updates the database of items and returns a 204 (no content) with header links to the updated single items.
- As `GET` is not allowed, there is no "subsequent GET" request to that resource which might violate the obligation of `HTTP`'s `PUT` to have an "equivalent representation" to the `PUT` request's representation. (cf. [rfc7231 section 4.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4))
- the server can implement the update in an idempotent way.

Problems with that approach:

I have not figured out yet how to make it HATEOAS compliant. Probably, there should be a "collection" link in every `items/{item_id}` resource representation to the `items` resource and an "edit" link which points to the `updateitems` resource.  Should I *hide* the possibility to `PUT` a single item in order to point the clients toward the "bulk edit"? (cf. [iana link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/linkrelations.xhtml))

It seems to me as if my approach is compliant with any REST or HTTP requirement that I can think of. However, I have the impression that I somehow misused the semantics and clients will have a hard time figuring out how to actually use this API.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!